# jquery dform plugin load from json?

Tags: jquery, json, forms

I am using JQuery dForm plugin to create a form. It works with the following code:

```
$("#myform").dform({
            "action" : "index.html",
            "method" : "get",
            "html" :
            [
                {
                    "type" : "p",
                    "html" : "You must login"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "username",
                    "id" : "txt-username",
                    "caption" : "Username",
                    "type" : "text",
                    "placeholder" : "E.g. user@example.com"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "password",
                    "caption" : "Password",
                    "type" : "password"
                },
                {
                    "type" : "submit",
                    "value" : "Login"
                }
            ]
        });
```

But If I move the form definition into a JSON file like:

```
"action" : "index.html",
            "method" : "get",
            "html" :
            [
                {
                    "type" : "p",
                    "html" : "You must login"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "username",
                    "id" : "txt-username",
                    "caption" : "Username",
                    "type" : "text",
                    "placeholder" : "E.g. user@example.com"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "password",
                    "caption" : "Password",
                    "type" : "password"
                },
                {
                    "type" : "submit",
                    "value" : "Login"
                }
            ]
```

And try to load the form definition from the json with:

```
$("#myform").dform('test.json', function(data) {
          this //-> Generated $('#myform')
          data //-> data from path/to/form.json
        });
```

The form does not load. Do I need to put something else in the JSon file or in the code?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Carlos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem in the JSon. Basically a JSon DForm definition can be:

```
{"id":"form","action":"","html" :[{"type" : "p","html" : "You must login"},{"name" : "username","id" : "txt-username","caption" : "Username","type" : "text","placeholder" : "E.g. user@example.com","onkeypress":"myKeypress"},{"name" : "password","caption" : "Password","type" : "password","onkeypress":"myKeypress"}]}
```

Carlos.